# How to hide field based on condition check in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to hide the `Textbox` inside the list view based on a condition.

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="lvAccessPoints" Background="#ff1d1d1d" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="ConnectionWifi" Foreground="White" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Padding="10,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="23"
                 Margin="10,10,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text=""
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="120"
                 TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                 Visibility="{Binding Name!=SelectedItem.Name ? Hidden : Visible}"/>
                        <Button Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I am trying like this , and its not seems to be the right way, what i want is when the particular name in the loop matches the selected items name, then only `TextBox` should show.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of expressions are not supported in XAML:

```
Visibility="{Binding Name!=SelectedItem.Name ? Hidden : Visible}"
```

What you could do is to define a `DataTrigger` in your `DataTemplate` that sets the `Visibility` property of the `TextBox` to `Visible` when the parent `ListViewItem` is selected:

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="lvAccessPoints" Background="#ff1d1d1d" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="ConnectionWifi" Foreground="White" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Padding="10,0" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         x:Name="txt"
                         Height="23"
                         Margin="10,10,0,0"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Text=""
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Width="120"
                         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"
                         Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <Button Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>
            </WrapPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```